# Javascript label + checkbox click problem in IE, replacing a checkbox with an image

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, forms, checkbox

Having an issue on my form here:

http://lexusevents.sanscode.com/datawash/details/pagetwo/1a08c087bdd3f0f85359a2a2e61ca74a

Basically what you have there is a bunch of `<img>`'s sitting inside a label with a checkbox like this:

```
<label for="mybox">
  <input type="checkbox" id="mybox">
  <img src="">
</label>
```

When you click the image in firefox or chrome, the label fires the checkbox and my crafty CSS styles change the image to have some text sit on top indicating it is selected.

Now the issue is that when i'm in IE, the label click doesn't work. It won't fire the checkbox. So without fully knowing why I decided I should try to use jquery to fix it.

```
    if ($.browser.msie) {


        $('.checkbox label').bind('click', function() {

        checkbx = $(this).children('input');
            me = $(this);
            checkbx.click();

            if (checkbx.is(':checked')) me.addClass('checked');
            else me.removeClass('checked');
        });

        $('.checkbox label').each(function() {
            var c = $('input', this);
            var me = $(this);

            if (c.is(':checked')) me.addClass('checked');
            else me.removeClass('checked');
        });

    }
```

This code has an error on the line that starts with `checkbx = $(th`... apparently there is a property doesn't support this method error but i can't work out why.

Can anybody help me out here?

Answer (score 0):

This might due to the other input in your form:

```
// You are selecting here all the input tag.
checkbx = $(this).children('input');
```

As per your html, you also had this tag:

```
<input type="hidden" name="form_id" value="1a08c087bdd3f0f85359a2a2e61ca74a">
```

That might cause an issue in IE. You might want to change your query:

From:

```
checkbx = $(this).children('input');
```

To (Most likely like this or be more specific in the query to select only input type of checkbox):

```
checkbx = $(this).children(':checkbox');
```